# Understanding if and only if conditional statement.

Tags: logic, soft-question, propositional-calculus

I was generalizing some result and I am stuck with with the *if and if conditions*. I have following conditions
in my statement:

Statement $P$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $n$ is odd and $n\geq 2r+1$.

What I got from this is :

If statement $P$ is true then $n$ is odd and $n\geq 2r+1$.

and

If $n$ is odd and $n\geq 2r+1$ then statement $P$ is true.

***My doubt :*** I just want to know the if $n = 2r+2$ and $n$ is even, does it imply the negation of statement $P$ i.e.,

$n = 2r+2$ and $n$ is even $\Rightarrow$ **NOT** statement $P$.

Is this correct? If not then kindly rectify me. Thanks for the help.

Comment: $2r+1$ is odd...

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: You missed one occurence of $2r+1$ in your edit. I fixed it for you.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Thank you :)

Comment: And I think you will find your answer here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have that "$A\implies B$", then the negation of $B$ implies the negation of $A$ (what is known as [contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition)). In your case, you would have that 
$$\text{NOT "$n$ is odd and $n\ge2r+1$"}\implies\mbox{NOT "Statement P"}$$

But be careful, the negation of "$n$ is odd and $n\ge2r+1$" is "$n$ is even OR $n<2r+1$".